# If I have a Riak DB, should it store to Amazon S3 or to the EC/2 instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, riak

I am setting up an Amazon EC/2 instance, and am putting Riak on it. I am wondering if I should store the data locally (and not ever delete the instance), or set up Riak to store to S3 and bring up/take down instances as I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For persistent data you should use an [Elastic Block Store](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) (EBS) volume; this is persistent across system restarts and can be attached to different EC2 instances at will.

Comment: Thank you Gareth again! I am thinking I will setup 3 Ec-2 instances with each one attached to an EBS volume (this is where riak will store its data). I can then setup the riak DBs in a cluster and they will sync from there on out. I can then write a ruby script (using chef??)  that will bring up a new ec-2 instance if I need it, attach a disk, and sync riak with the others in the cluster.

Am I thinking about this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to ask on the mailing list: http://lists.basho.com/mailman/listinfo/riak-users_lists.basho.com

There's also lots of information on the wiki: http://wiki.basho.com/display/RIAK/Home